# error: unable to handle compilation, expected exactly one compiler job in ''

Tags: eosio-code, eosio.cdt, eosio-cpp

I am not able to compile, getting

```
error: unable to handle compilation, expected exactly one compiler job in ''
```

not able to compile a simple hello world smart contract

Comment: Too little information. Can you provide your case in detail, OS, CDT version, the way you try to build (just calling eosio-cpp or use cmake) etc?

Comment: mac mojave, CDT v1.6.1. 
docker run --rm --name eosio.cdt_v1.6.1 --volume /Users/bhaskaran/Documents/helloworld:/project -w /project eostudio/eosio.cdt:v1.6.1 /bin/bash -c "eosio-cpp -abigen -I include -R  -contract helloworld -o helloworld.wasm src/helloworld.cpp"

error: unable to handle compilation, expected exactly one compiler job in ''
Error while processing /project/helloworld.
abigen error

Comment: still struggling to fix this. need help

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem and i was able to fix it by creating an include folder and put the .hpp file there and change the `#include ".hpp"` to `#include <.hpp>` from .cpp file.

Answer (score -1):

eosio-cpp build command parameters were wrong. i am able to fix it by setting the right include path

Comment: Bhaskar do you mind elaborating on how the include paths changed?  I'm running into the same issue with a default new project in ESIO studio with everything latest.  Tried all sorts of include paths nothing works..

Comment: Its great that you solved your own problem, and providing a full, detailed explanation of your solution will help others in the future.